# Why would a build on a self hosted build agent be able to build during the day by either scheduled or manual, but only by manual at night?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We have self hosted build agents on Azure VMs. The problems that we are having is, when sending builds of a specific project to the agents, they will build just fine during the day either by scheduled build or manual execution. But, at night only manual execution will work. Why would that be?

Comment: This is in Azure. The machine is a VM in Azure and build agent was installed on the VM. What other information could be needed from me for someone to be able to answer this question?

Comment: Did you tested it with another pipeline? You could also share pipeline definition and check for potential trigger issues (you can find them in 3-dot menu of the specific pipeline just above settings)

Comment: I have MS support involved, I will keep this question updated on the results of that.